# getting regex with specific number of slashes in text

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have the following text

```
http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/ausland/amerika/venezuela-das-ende-der-sozialistischen-epoche-13952597.html
http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/ausland/bundeswehr-einsatz-von-der-leyen-gesteht-fehler-in-afghanistan-ein-13952438.html
http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/inland/bayerns-ehrenamtliche-in-der-fluechtlingskrise-13948777.html
```

I would like to retrieve only those links that start with `http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/` but end with `.html` with only one slash in between. Basically, avoiding the first link in the list above.

I tried the following
`http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/.*/.*?\.html`

However, all get selected. How do avoid the extra slash in the first? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
http://www\.faz\.net/aktuell/politik/[^/]*/[^/]*\.html
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zC4bB9/1)

Comment: Just FYI: in Python, there is no need escaping `/`. [`http://www\.faz\.net/aktuell/politik/[^/]+/[^/]+\.html`](https://regex101.com/r/zC4bB9/2).